# Variable Number of Entry Fields in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to create a widget that contains an amount of entry fields based on the an aspect of a file that's loaded in.

I've been using

```
self.e = Entry(self.master);
self.e.pack();
self.e.delete(0,END);
self.e.insert(0, 0);
```

to create each entry but ideally want to iterate on this command. Each entry variable should have a different name so I can call each individual cell, which I don't know if that is possible.

More generally, what I'm trying to do is create a n by 1 table where the user can input an integer to the cells and I can access that value in another function.

Answer (score 3):

> More generally, what I'm trying to do is create a n by 1 table...

Use a `list` and append however many `Entry` widgets are needed.

> Each entry variable should have a different name so I can call each
>   individual cell

Simply index the list (of course you *could* set it up to create new instance variables but you probably don't actually want that).

You can even put your setup code in a function and call that each time.

```
def create_entry_widget(self, x):
    new_widget = Entry(self.master)
    new_widget.pack()
    new_widget.insert(0, x)
    return new_widget
```

All you need to do is define `self.n` based on your file.

```
self.entry_widgets = [self.create_entry_widget(x) for x in xrange(self.n)]
```

**NOTE:** Don't use semicolons `;` at the end of each line in Python.